# Remove duplicates in excel 2016 based on data in multiple columns

Tags: excel

I want to remove duplicate rows in excel 2016 based on data from multiple columns.

For example I have a row with columns. I have another row where all the values in the exact same columns match the first one, I want to get rid of it. But I want this to be an if and oly if and if for example there 5 columns in the first row, the duplicates must have 5 same columns as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far, if anything? This question doesn't show any evidence of research or any attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: This is the research. Sorry if I offended you by my sloth

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a helper column and insert a formula to concatenate the contents of all columns

After that apply conditional formatting on that new column to highlight the duplicate values, these duplicate values would the ones you require.

[image]

Formula in Cell G3 is

```
=B3 & C3 & D3 & E3 & F3
```